# Vitamio more than one video playback

Tags: android, vitamio

`activity1` is playing video, and then jump to `activity2` to play another video, and then return to the `activity1` from `activity2`, `activity1` has been recovered.

Comment: use SavedInstance State for that

Comment: I have used the SavedInstance, press the home key and jump does not play the video activity, are normal, as long as the activity2 play video, the video is playing activity1, activity1 will be recycled